# In prestashop, export total days total order. with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prestashop

I have a table with orders. I want to populate another table with the days total. For each day of the year I want one row with total.

I wrote this one, I think that big problem is in the date format.

I ask if the syntax is correct

I need to do something like in this example because in the complete version I need to change some variables: `$somma_paid` if currency change..

I used "if" and start with first day of year and I modify it with `strtotime`

I need help to complete it.

Final result will be populate a new table (`data`, `totale`, `merce`, `servizi`, `numero`) with 365 rows. Each row has a day total.

```
$date1 = 2013-01-01;
$somma_paid = 0;
$somma_products = 0;
$somma_shipping = 0;


$query55 = "SELECT id_order, total_paid, payment, total_products, id_currency, total_shipping, shipping_number, delivery_date FROM ps_orders WHERE delivery_date LIKE '%2013%'";
$result55 = mysql_query($query55) or die(mysql_error());

 while ($row55 = mysql_fetch_array($result55))
{
    $currency = $row55['id_currency'];
    $id = $row55['id_order'];
    $date = $row55['delivery_date'];

    if ($date == $date1)  {

        echo '
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 120px;">' . $id . '</td>
            <td style="width: 120px;">' . $row55['delivery_date'] . '</td>
            <td style="width: 170px;">' . $row55['payment'] . '</td>
            <td style="width: 100px;">' . $row55['total_paid'] . '</td>
            <td style="width: 100px;">' . $row55['total_products'] . '</td>
            <td style="width: 100px;">' . $row55['total_shipping'] . '</td>
            <td style="width: 158px;">' . $row55['shipping_number'] . '</td>
        </tr>   
        ';

        $somma_paid += $row55['total_paid'];
        $somma_products += $row55['total_products'];
        $somma_shipping += $row55['total_shipping'];
    }
    else 
    {
        $query1122 = "REPLACE INTO calendar (data, totale, merce, servizi, numero) VALUES('$date', '$somma_paid', '$somma_products', '$somma_shipping')";
        $result1122 = mysql_query($query1122) or die(mysql_error());

        $somma_paid = 0;
        $somma_products = 0;
         somma_shipping = 0;

        $date1 = strtotime($date."+ 1 day");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the query to get already the formatted data, using a group by day to have a row for each day of the year, replace your select with :

```
SELECT date(delivery_date) as data, SUM(total_paid) as totale, SUM(total_products) as merce, SUM(total_shipping) as servizi, COUNT(DISTINCT id_order) as numero 
FROM ps_orders 
WHERE YEAR(delivery_date) = '2013' 
GROUP BY DAY(delivery_date) ORDER BY data
```

This way you can have all the data that just need to be exported. (You can use a INSERT INTO calendar (data, totale, merce, servizi, numero) SELECT ...) or perform a foreach on your rows and make it with php insert like you was already doing, taking care of "void" days where you don't have any data.

**UPDATE**

if you need to perform conversion before inserting in to your new table you can perform a select by date, and then loop over the rows to convert the info when you need. After the conversion store all your data inside an array that uses the given data as key (again, if you want all the day of a year you can initialize your array with a for() and create all 365 entries even if some will remain empty.

This is an example based on your code on how you can get and order the data:

```
$query55 = "SELECT date(delivery_date) as data, total_paid as totale, total_products as merce, total_shipping as servizi, id_order as numero, id_currency as valuta 
FROM ps_orders 
WHERE YEAR(delivery_date) = '2013' 
ORDER BY data ASC";
$result55 = mysql_query($query55) or die(mysql_error());

$calendario_array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result55))
    {

    if(!isset($calendario_array[$row['data']]))
        $calendario_array[$row['data']] = array(
            'data' => $row['data'], //redundant but useful for fast insert
            'totale' => 0,
            'merce' => 0,
            'servizi' => 0,
            'numero' => 0

        );


    switch($row['valuta'])
    {
        case(1): //convert value based on your id_currency
            $row['merce'] = convertValue($row['merce']);
            $row['totale'] = convertValue($row['totale']);
            $row['servizi'] = convertValue($row['servizi']);
            break;
        case(2): //convert value based on your id_currency 
            $row['merce'] = convertValue($row['merce']);
            $row['totale'] = convertValue($row['totale']);
            $row['servizi'] = convertValue($row['servizi']);
            break;
    }
        $calendario_array[$row['data']]['numero'] = $calendario_array $row['data']]['numero'] + 1;
        $calendario_array[$row['data']]['merce'] = $calendario_array[$row['data']]['merce'] + $row['merce'];
        $calendario_array[$row['data']]['totale'] = $calendario_array[$row['data']]['totale'] + $row['totale'];
        $calendario_array[$row['data']]['servizi'] = $calendario_array[$row['data']]['merce'] + $row['servizi'];

    }

//$calendario_array now contains all your data, you can cycle on it to perform the insert
foreach($calendario_array as $row)
    //insert or update data in calendario table
```

**UPDATE v2**

As for the last part, to insert the data inside the new table i suggest to perform a conversion from the `$calendar_array` to a query string, that will perform all the insert at once. This way we won't face performance issue. Bare in mind that i won't take care of truncate the table to clear previous data i will leave it to your choice. as for the data field i suppose you are storing it as datetime, if not you will have to edit the data to get the desired format.

```
$insert_string = array(); //lets create a clear array that will contain a string for each entry. this will represent our insert value row

foreach($calendario_array as $row){ //cycle through the calendario array, store the data as a VALUES ( ) string
    $insert_string[] = '("'.$row['data'].' 00:00:00",'.$row['merce'].','.$row['totale'].','.$row['servizi'].','.$row['numero'].')';
}

$insert_query = 'INSERT INTO ps_calendar (data, merce, totale, servizi, numero) VALUES '.implode(',', $insert_string).';'; //implode the array containing all the data.

$result = mysql_query($insert_query )or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: thanks, but i cannot use SUM because i need to convert all valure to EUR before generate total

Comment: thanks a lot, but i have big difficulty on ultimate part. How can i insert all total rows in my new table? thnaks a lot

Comment: updated again to show how i would perform an easy insert inside the ps_calendar table

Comment: i tried it but it do not populate my table, no errors. I should modify/insert something before execute it?

Comment: sorry now works, but if i tried to do again i have "Duplicate entry". ishould use replace into?

Comment: Yes, i didn't wrote all the code you should use. this is just a guide line to write your own version. If you don't TRUNCATE the calendar table you should use replace into, or check against a single row and perform an update. plus i don't know how it's made your table, if you have UNIQUE key or other fields with Constraint.